# The different sounding of the keys

Tags: key

What do you think different keys sounds like? For example, d minor is saddest key or c minor is the most drammatic one. I don't really understand what is the differnce between all of them, because any melody will be the same in any key. What do you think? Is there a difference?

Comment: Compulsory [Spinal Tap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgViOqGJEvM) link.

Comment: There may well have been differences when instruments were tuned in other intonations rather than the common present day 12tet.